# Peewee join with duplicated foreign-keys

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql, orm, peewee

I have this model:

```
class UserAssignment(BaseModel):
    user = peewee.ForeignKeyField(User, backref='assignments')
    worker = peewee.ForeignKeyField(Worker)
    assigner = peewee.ForeignKeyField(User, backref='assignations')
```

I'm making this query:

```
assignments = (
    UserAssignment
        .select(
            User,
            UserAssignment,
            Worker
        )
        .join(User)
        .switch(UserAssignment)
        .join(Worker)
        .switch(UserAssignment)
        .where(
            UserAssignment.user_id == user_id,
            UserAssignment.active == True,
        )
)
```

Looking at the postgres log, I'm seeing that is making N extra queries for each `assigner` (which is the same model as `user`). I'm not sure how to create such join.

What I've tried:

- Repeating the join with the `on` clause:

  ```
  assignments = (
      UserAssignment
          .select(
              User,
              UserAssignment,
              Worker
          )
          .join(User, on=UserAssignment.user)
          .switch(UserAssignment)
          .join(User, on=UserAssignment.assigner)
          .switch(UserAssignment)
          .join(Worker)
          .switch(UserAssignment)
          .where(
              UserAssignment.user_id == user_id,
              UserAssignment.active == True,
          )
  )
  ```

  Throwing an error because the table name was specified twice.

Answer (score 0):

I should have RTFM twice. I'm gonna share my own answer for future reference.

I just needed a table alias:

```
Assigner = User.alias()
assignments = (
    UserAssignment
        .select(
            Assigner,
            User,
            UserAssignment,
            Worker
        )
        .join(User, on=UserAssignment.user_id == User.id)
        .switch(UserAssignment)
        .join(Assigner, on=UserAssignment.assigner_id == Assigner.id)
        .switch(UserAssignment)
        .join(Worker)
        .switch(UserAssignment)
        .where(
            UserAssignment.user_id == user_id,
            UserAssignment.active == True,
        )
)
```